# Proving the series sin(n+1)-sin(n+2) converges or diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

As the title states, I'm trying to determine whether the series $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin(n+1)-\sin(n+2)$$ converges or diverges. My intuition is saying diverging since the sines are oscillating. How will I go about 'formally' proving this?

I searched online for this and I got an 'explanation' saying $s_n=\sin(2)-\sin(n+2)$. Where did this even come from, and how does this prove anything?

Comment: Write down a few terms of the summation, and note that cancellations will occur.

Comment: Use the definition of convergence or divergence of infinite series via their partial sums. That's what those $s_n$ have to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

First: your sum diverges. To see this, write it out and note that it is a telescoping series- all but two of the terms cancel. Thats how you get your $s_n$. Then note that the value of the nth partial sum is actually a linear combination of $\sin(n)$, whose limit does not exist, therefore the limit of $s_n$ does not exist.

Comment: This isn't accurate.  Why does $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin(n)$ fail to exist when $n\in \mathbb{N}$?  While it is not difficult to show that the limit doesn't exist, the underlying reason is the irrationality of $\pi$.

Comment: @Dr. MV Can you explain further why the underlying reason is the irrationality of $\pi$?

Comment: @Dr.MV: even if $\pi$ were irrational, $\lim_{n\to \infty}\sin(n)$ would still fail to converge. (I realise I have strayed into a counterfactual minefield here, but I hope you see what I mean.)

Comment: @TonyK How would you define $\sin(x)$ in your counterfactual world?

Comment: @DrMV: I didn't think you would make me spell it out, but here goes: To show that $\sin n$ doesn't converge, you don't need to use the irrationality of $\pi$. You just use the addition formula for $\sin(n+1)$ to show that if $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small, then $|\sin n| < \epsilon \implies |\sin(n+1)| > \frac12\sin 1$.

Comment: @Aperson123: this is not an answer, you are just handwaving on the crucial part. How would you deal with $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\left[\sin((n+2)!e)-\sin((n+1)!e)\right]$$ for instance?

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio that is not an answer. The question is why this has anything to do with the irrationality of $\pi$. At least, that is my question.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Can you give an example of a continuous periodic function with constant  non zero amplitude with zero limit? Also the function you are giving is not the one in the question, so I don't have to deal with it.

Comment: @TonyK So, I presume that you are assuming that the sine function is completely characterized by the functional equation $f(x+y)=f(x)g(y)+f(y)g(x)$.  Well, $f(x)=0$ satisfies that functional equation and converges to $0$.  So, you need something else in your new world.

Comment: @Dr.MV: You said "the underlying reason is the irrationality of $\pi$", which is not true. Yes, you can make anything depend on the irrationality of $\pi$, because $\pi\in\mathbb Q\implies$ pigs can fly. But that doesn't make it an _underlying reason_ for pigs not being able to fly.

Comment: @Aperson123: you are exploiting that $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sin(n)$ does not exist, but for instance $\lim_{n\to+\infty}\sin(\pi n)$ does exist.

Comment: The $n$-th partial sums just depends on $\sin(n+2)$ and that **does not** have a "decreasing amplitude". It simply does not have a limit.

Comment: @TonyK Your refutation was based on a functional equation only, which does not fully characterize the sine function.  The sine function can be characterized fully by a set of conditions, one of which is continuity and another of which is its $2\pi$ periodicity - where $\pi$ is the real-world irrational number.  So, what is the sine function again in your "counter factual" world?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I see what you mean. Do the edits by A.W Grossbard fix it? That way we can rely entirely on the divergence of $\sin(n)$, an agreed upon fact.

Comment: @Aperson123: now the answer is correct, but still does not explain why $\sin(n)$ does not have a limit, that is the crucial point. To exploit the irrationality of $\pi$ for achieving such a task is just a standard and straightforward way, but there are others, of course.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, the $N$th partial sum of the series in this problem is $\sin 2 - \sin (N+2).$ So to show the series diverges, it's enough to show $\sin n,n=1,2,\dots$ diverges.

We can prove this by noting that $e^{in}$ lands in the arc $A=\{e^{it}: \pi/4 < t < 3\pi/4\}$ infinitely many times. Thus $\sin n > 1/\sqrt 2$ for infinitely many $n.$ Similarly, $\sin n <- 1/\sqrt 2$ for infinitely many $n.$ It follows that $\sin n$ diverges.

Why must we have $e^{in}\in A$ infinitely many times? As $n$ goes through $1,2,\dots ,$ $e^{in}$ marches clockwise around the unit circle in steps of arc length $1.$ The arc $A$ has arc length $\pi/2 >1.$ Once every full orbit of the circle, $e^{in}$ has to land in $A,$ since it can't "jump over" an arc of length $>1$ by taking steps of length $1.$ So in fact $e^{in}\in A$ at least once in every $7$ consecutive values of $n$ ($7>2\pi !$).